# Keyboard pop ups at landscape change orientation

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, samsung-mobile

When device is rotated from portrait to landscape, keyboard keeps popping up. This happens without being any EditText on the screen. I tested with several devices and it happens only on Samsung devices. Is there a way to prevent keyboard pop ups?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code in the activity's onCreate method to make sure the keyboard only pops up when a user clicks into an EditText

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Tested.

Answer (score 1):

Are you tried this one in your manifest file`android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"`

Answer (score 0):

Add to root element `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` attribute.